# Password reset on Firebase with VueJs

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I want to reset the password with Vuejs. I managed to send the reset password link with my custom url, and when the users click on it it redirects to a custom form. Password reset url is:

http://localhost:8080/passwordreset?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=viIqct7-jvuNnZxMEgyyRualxpX5CmZ3_EJrCQi-C88AAAFeuLXmWg&apiKey=AIzaSyBaCCvq-ZEfQmdrL7fmElXDjZF_J-tku2I

```
<input type="password" v-model="passwordNew" class="" placeholder="New password">

<input type="password" v-model="passwordConfirm"class=""placeholder="Confirm Password">

<button class="btn" v-on:click="resetPassword">Reset Password</button>
```

My password reset file is a `component`, under my `<script>` i have:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
export default {

    data: function() {
        return {
            passwordNew: '',
            passwordConfirm: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        resetPassword: function() {
            var newPassword = this.passwordNew

            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            console.log ("  User:  "+ user );

            user.updatePassword(newPassword).then(function() {
              // Update successful.
              alert("Reset Password successful")
            }).catch(function(error) {
              // An error happened.
            });

        },
        checkPasswords: function () {

        }
    }

}
```

All I get when the user sets the new password is on console that user is null, see image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using this incorrectly.
When you are sending a reset password email, it means the user is not logged in. When you update a password, the user is already logged in.
In your case, you need to call `auth.confirmPasswordReset(code, newPass)`. For more on this API, check: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#confirmPasswordReset

For more on building your own password reset landing page, check: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

Comment: Well i need an example code to help me get, should i remove all my implemented code and use the examples from that documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler